Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop, used as Jellyfin Media Server, crashes when streaming
I'm running a dockerized Jellyfin media server on my Ubuntu Desktop, which I'm using as a home server. The server worked fine for about a year, up until 2 weeks ago.
Now, the server crashes randomly while streaming media.
The screen goes black, and the server becomes unreachable. I have to physically unplug the power cable to restart it. The issue persists regardless of whether the media is stored on an external hard drive or internal SSD.
Upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS did not resolve the issue. I have performed a CPU stress test without crashes, so I don't think it's a CPU issue, as in the PC overheating during transcoding.
The Ubuntu GUI app Logs shows these important logs right before/during the crash:
14:06:29 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2567.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
14:06:29 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2567.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
14:06:29 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2569.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
14:06:27 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
14:06:12 (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
14:06:12 (uetoothd): sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
14:06:12 (uetoothd): profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.


These are my Journalctl Logs:

May 21 14:06:20 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: Starting docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine...
May 21 14:06:20 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:20.486890124+02:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
May 21 14:06:20 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:20.494222845+02:00" level=info msg="detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
May 21 14:06:20 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:20.646985479+02:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
May 21 14:06:20 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:20.704094928+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.031273596+02:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 97a62ce914deb45a60a3d898d05c7b2c430e56e093bdc05ad37b15759f63986d (168a430ceefb9d61aa7d64911a9b66818fcc9abcd380366ac8764abe0ef7cee0)"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.037679534+02:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 563e64e4b6cf85ef42b2c655ee492371f2232a2523ab0cefd88e39e63d6ba59f 01c5ff7d379ace2ed908245bea66e5785c91354c77f8ef919ea39b5acd733744], retrying...."
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.044589931+02:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox a6ceb5e4e2e9c0cb749c8222793e5ab0447274a8ae4050c9a6caf29e655d8e8c (1e9c84a8598ab701b3cd8a8b2db90e06844817dd6486d3a63d0e53d5f4cd04ee)"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.045780834+02:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint d33809439d80a0884b1d96c9340ff1edd67757564a94f29cc335d5d6a96c7fa8 23c57352e27aa5306188fe033044664ff0e6d45c835421a4a2d36d1be6f69c58], retrying...."
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.049629732+02:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 3be8a3af2340140dac332665fee057fecd5d8ed965fbf3bc33425cbb24c606d0 (a14b8f0f4b8b57c4885dcc85b29b0fe56fdde8d7f27295129e0b0c09ddeb7ab4)"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.055786166+02:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 9f3d9ce435d3587c92588f96095a2a3cd2517dede597408638787b0165ebd539 8c477a1b17fdf9d790d11bd53300ac14559c9e1b5d46243064fd4074de8561cb], retrying...."
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.140431107+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.245500206+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.429472074+02:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.429714195+02:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.440113096+02:00" level=error msg="168a430ceefb9d61aa7d64911a9b66818fcc9abcd380366ac8764abe0ef7cee0 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: container \"168a430ceefb9d61aa7d64911a9b66818fcc9abcd380366ac8764abe0ef7cee0\" in namespace \"moby\": not found"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.478361561+02:00" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=168a430ceefb9d61aa7d64911a9b66818fcc9abcd380366ac8764abe0ef7cee0 error="failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting \"/mnt/lukshdd/Cosmos_Server/Jellyfin/TV_Shows\" to rootfs at \"/data/tvshows\": stat /mnt/lukshdd/Cosmos_Server/Jellyfin/TV_Shows: no such file or directory: unknown"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.566354805+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.594866824+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=8e96db1 containerd-snapshotter=false storage-driver=overlay2 version=26.1.3
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.595438536+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:06:21.651083891+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
May 21 14:06:21 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
May 21 14:24:08 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:24:08.141471190+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers"
May 21 14:24:08 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: 2024/05/21 14:24:08 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.(*respWriterWrapper).WriteHeader (wrap.go:98)
May 21 14:29:40 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: 2024/05/21 14:29:40 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.(*respWriterWrapper).WriteHeader (wrap.go:98)
May 21 14:29:40 ubuntu-server dockerd[1852]: time="2024-05-21T14:29:40.987355817+02:00" level=error msg="Error streaming logs: invalid character '{' in string escape code" container=1e9c84a8598ab701b3cd8a8b2db90e06844817dd6486d3a63d0e53d5f4cd04ee method="(*Daemon).ContainerLogs" module=daemon spanID=6ba75d3aa001cb96 traceID=002577f32ecca114d4b5e073df8afd1b


I just don't get what the issue is and would be incredibly thankful for any kind of help!

An upgrade of the OS never fixes a problem it just carries it over.

I did a clean install, not only an upgrade, that's why I was hoping, that upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 would fix the issue.

You may want to edit and correct the question it says upgrade.
